# How can I replace the inputAccessoryView with another one unnoticed by the user?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

I have requirements, that it is necessary to show one `inputAccessoryView` for the software keyboard and another for the hardware keyboard. I made a separate manager which includes `NotificationCenter`, after receiving the notification I calculate the software or hardware is being used at the moment. After that I try to replace the first `inputAccessoryView` with the one that should be used with the hardware keyboard, but I have a flicker when I call `textView.reloadInputViews()`, I tried it without animation, but it does not help. Please tell me how can I replace `inputAccessoryView` not noticeable for the user? Thank you.

code example

```
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        // test
        if KeyboardManager.shared.isHardwareKeyboard {
            let redView = UIView()
            redView.backgroundColor = .red
            redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 100)
            textView?.inputAccessoryView = redView
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                self.textView?.reloadInputViews()
            }
        }
    }
```

Update: Of course, the best option would be to know which keyboard is used and add only the `inputAccessoryView` that is needed at the moment, but unfortunately Apple does not allow it.